# SQL JOIN multi-part identifier error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables, `Customers [CustomerID, Email]` and History[CustomerID, BikeID, Checkout, StationIDout, Checkin, StationIDin].

Given a customer's e-mail, I want to query the `History` table and obtain all rows containing that email's corresponding `CustomerID` where the bike has been returned (`WHERE Checkin IS NOT NULL`), ordering by most recent `Checkin` date.

I tried the following query but am getting the error:

> "The multi-part identifier "test_email@test.org" could not be bound."

test_email@test.org exists in the database. I saw other posts explaining how it's either a typo or some column is being wrongly selected, but I don't see my query doing any of these. Is there something else I'm missing?

```
email = "test_email@test.org";

 sql = string.Format(@"
    SELECT BikeID, Checkout, StationIDout, Checkin, StationIDin 
    FROM History INNER JOIN 
    Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = History.CustomerID
    AND Customers.Email = {0} 
    WHERE Checkin IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY Checkin DESC", email);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing string quotes:

```
 sql = string.Format(@"
    SELECT BikeID, Checkout, StationIDout, Checkin, StationIDin 
    FROM History INNER JOIN 
    Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = History.CustomerID
    AND Customers.Email = '{0}' 
                          ^   ^
    WHERE Checkin IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY Checkin DESC", email);
```

But rather than using concat or format, use parameters

Comment: D'oh! Thank you. This worked. So I don't forget, why does single quotes  around the parameter solve this issue?

Comment: because that's the expected TSQL syntax for comparing strings (presumably so that spaces (and white space) can be included in a string)